# Python - ImportError: cannot import name 'db'

Tags: python

I have a project with the following directories and files structure:

[image]

I have this line of code in `application.py`:

```
db = MongoEngine()
```

Which i'd like to import to `models.py` using:

```
from application import db
```

But i get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'db'
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.
It's a `Flask` project and i was using deprecated imports:

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine import MongoEngine
from flask.ext.script ...
```

Which are now:

`flask_script` and `flask_mongoengine`.